# QVector preallocated access thread safety

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety

Qt containers are safe as read-only when used by multiple threads. But what about write access? Can I resize a `QVector` and use `operator[]` in different threads for writing? The size of the `QVector` will  stay constant, each thread will write in different memory location (own index for each thread), so no same memory simultaneous access. The `QVector` will be a global variable.

Comment: If each thread writes to a separate part of the vector, you don't need all this data in a single vector. Have a per-thread vector.

Comment: @KubaOber Actually I do, I need to ensure that order of the vector is the same as if I had a single-thread application. It would be harder if I tried to join the vectors after threads are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt documentation defines QVector's member functions as [reentrant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html), which means that it's safe to call its methods from threads if you have different instances of QVector for each thread. This means that QVector isn't going to be thread safe the way you are intending to use it.

If you can guarantee that your writes to your QVector won't alter its length and won't overlap, you may find that you won't have problems. But if you know you're going to be writing to different areas of your vector, why not split the vector into subvectors and work on each subvector with a thread? This will allow you to make a guarantee that you won't have thread-related trouble. When your work is done, you can replace the vector as a single entity.